# Play/Pause HTML5 Video on screen size

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I'm wanting to play/pause videos based on screen size, for example, I want the video to autoplay on desktop, but pause on tablet and below. Here is the Javascript I've been playing with so far.

Markup:

```
    <video id="cdev-video-selector" class="cdev-video-controls" autoplay controls loop>
            <source src="samplesource">
        </video>
```

JS:

```
$('#cdev-video-selector') {
   if ($(window).width() < 960) {
$('#cdev-video-selector').pause();
   } else {
$('#cdev-video-selector').play();
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `autoplay` if you plan to trigger the JS's `.play()` depending on the window size:

```
<video id="cdev-video-selector" controls loop>
```

You need to target the resize on the `window` object: ***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/qojiqi/5/edit)***

<sub>**jQuery:**</sub>

```
var $vid = $("#cdev-video-selector");
function videoHandler(){
    $vid[0][ $(window).width()<960 ? "pause" : "play" ]();
}
$(window).on("resize load", videoHandler);
```

<sub>***[Plain JS jsBin demo:](http://jsbin.com/qojiqi/2/edit?html,js,console,output)***</sub>

```
var videoSel = document.getElementById("cdev-video-selector");

function videoHandler(){
  if(window.innerWidth < 960){
    videoSel.pause();
  }else{
    videoSel.play();
  }
}

window.addEventListener("resize", videoHandler, false);
window.addEventListener("load",   videoHandler, false);
```

If you like it you can also "simplify" the above function to: ***[demo](http://jsbin.com/qojiqi/3/edit?html,js,output)***

```
var videoSel = document.getElementById("cdev-video-selector");
function videoHandler(){
    videoSel[window.innerWidth<960?"pause":"play"]();
}
videoHandler();
window.addEventListener("resize", videoHandler, false);
```

Comment: This works almost perfectly, it works in pausing the video if I resize the browser. It still auto plays if the video starts at a size under 960px.